# Array.slice() parameter is not a function

Tags: javascript

Im encountering an odd problem when going through freeCodeCamp beta.

The "purpose" of this is not modifying the original array and using functional programming techniques to modify arrays.

However I keep getting complaints about the "array" parameter is the remove function not being a valid function:

```
//  the global variable
var bookList = [
    "The Hound of the Baskervilles",
    "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies",
    "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica",
    "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"];

/* This function should add a book to the list and return the list */
// New parameters should come before the bookName one

// Add your code below this line
function add (bookListTemp, bookName) {
  let newBookArr = bookListTemp;
  return newBookArr.push(bookName);
  // Add your code above this line
}

/* This function should remove a book from the list and return the list */
// New parameters should come before the bookName one

// Add your code below this line
function remove (bookList,bookName) {
  let newArr = bookList.slice();
  if (newArr.indexOf(bookName) >= 0) {

    return newArr.slice(0, 1, bookName);

    // Add your code above this line
    }
}

var newBookList = add(bookList, 'A Brief History of Time');
var newerBookList = remove(bookList, 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');
var newestBookList = remove(add(bookList, 'A Brief History of Time'),
    'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');

console.log(bookList);
```

In the remove function i've tried taking the parameter and doing array.slice() method as well as array.concat() method. Since doing `let newArr = bookList` doesn't actually make a new array correct? it just makes a new copy that references the original array correct?

The exact error I get is `TypeError: bookList.slice is not a function`

What's even weirder is `Array.isArray(bookList)` returns `true` (in the `function remove`. So I don't understand why it's complaining about array methods?

Comment: You have 2 calls to `remove`. Which one is giving you that error?

Comment: It says it's happening at the remove function. Jsfiddle points to `let newArr = bookList.slice();`

Comment: Your functions aren't returning the array. `[].push()` does not return the array, it returns the resulting length. `[].slice()` also does not return the full array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=example)

> return The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

You should return array instead

```
function add (bookListTemp, bookName) {
      let newBookArr = bookListTemp;
      newBookArr.push(bookName);
      // Add your code above this line
      return newBookArr;
    }
```

**OR**
Let's try [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=example) instead

```
function add (bookListTemp, bookName) {
  let newBookArr = bookListTemp;
  return newBookArr.concat(bookName);
  // Add your code above this line
}
```

Comment: Doesn't setting one array equal to the other just make a copy reference of the original...so if I end up changing this copy won't it mess up the original.

Comment: Yes. Because concat return new A new Array instance. So in my opinion, you don't need funtion add. Just using concat. And MDN is good document to reference. :)

Comment: unfortunately I cannot get rid of the add function for the challenge :/

Comment: OK. So if you want to you push, return newBookArr instead of newBookArr.push - see my edit post :)

Comment: Ended up fixing it by making sure to do .slice() into new arrays on each one. So when we normally copy an array like let arrnew = oldarray. if we change arrnew will it always change oldarray?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to copy the array without mutating it. You will not be able to use the `.slice()` method on the bookList, because it is an argument in the function and therefore not an array. The work around is `var newBookArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(bookListTemp);` or `[].slice.call(bookListTemp);`

This allows you to perform the slice on the bookList when it is an argument. The other way I discovered, when playing around with it - `var newBookArr = [].concat(bookListTemp);`

When trying `var newBookArr = [].push(bookListTemp);` we find the original bookList pushed inside the new array. So it is a copy, but as an array within an array. the `.concat()` method merges the old array into the new.